# How to deploy Apache superset using mod_wsgi that is installed in python3-venv?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, python-venv, apache-superset

I have installed apache superset and i need to run this through wsgi server using mod_wsgi of apache. Im new to python and configuring apache. I need help on what exactly my superset.wsgi would look like and my superset.conf would look like.

This is my conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess superset python-home=/var/www/superset
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/superset/superset.wsgi
    WSGIProcessGroup superset
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
     <Directory /var/www/>
            # set permissions as per apache2.conf file
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my superset.wsgi

```
import sys
import site

sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/superset')
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
site.addsitedir('/var/www/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages')

from superset import app as application
```

and this is my error in apache2/error.log

```
 Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/superset/superset.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
     obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]
   File "/var/www/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_>
     raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
 RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

 This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
 the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
 with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the `superset.wsgi`.
Accordingly to the [documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset#running-on-a-wsgi-http-server), the correct method to be invoked is `create_app()`. Then the wsgi file should be the following.

```
from superset.app import create_app
application = create_app()
```